# How to show SSD and RAM size using terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm a Mac Admin and was wondering if there is a quicker way to show the RAM and SSD sizes from terminal rather than running system_profiler, waiting for it to show the information, and then searching for it.

Anything would help.  I know ***system_profiler SPHardwareDataType*** shows the RAM and other information, but wondering if anyone knows a command that would just show SSD and RAM information.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: would these do: `df -h | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $2}'`  and `sysctl hw.memsize | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 10):

Memory size can be found with the command `sysctl hw.memsize`

You can convert this to a more human readable number if you need to:

```
hwmemsize=$(sysctl -n hw.memsize)
# 1024**3 = GB
ramsize=$(expr $hwmemsize / $((1024**3)))
echo "System Memory: ${ramsize} GB"
```

---

Volume size can be found with a short command like `df -hl`

Note: this does not differentiate between a HDD, SSD, or a Fusion drive. It will list any locally mounted volume.

Comment: This is a good answer (as system_profiler does not work on older macs). As for the math, it's worth clarifying that the resulting number is in bytes. Mine is 8589934592. Instead of code, you can use a calculator: divide by 2014 to get kb (8388608), again by 1024 to get MB (8192), and again by 1024 to get GB (8). Or use this page: http://www.csgnetwork.com/memconv.html

Answer (score 0):

Is `lsblk` available on/for that OS?

If yes, try:

> $ lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT,KNAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,RO,RM,STATE,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL
>   ...

*The output is instantaneous on Ubuntu.*

> $ man lsblk

Lists the keywords for the `-o` option. Pick the ones you need.

And for memory:

> cat /proc/meminfo
>   ...

or

> $ head -n 1 /proc/meminfo
>   MemTotal:       32883644 kB

Comment: Note: These might be Debian specific, AFAIK MacOS is "BSD"-type.